# Shopping Cart Price Rule that excludes discounted products

Tags: cart, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping

I've created a Catalog Price Rule on some products.
Now, I would to insert a ShoppingCart Price Rule (Coupon) that excludes the products concerned in the Catalog Price Rule.

Example:

Product A initial price: €120
Product A discounted price after Catalog Price Rule: €100
Product B price: €100

If a customer insert both products in the cart and the submit a Coupon Code it must be valid only for product B.

Is this operation possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Magento has an inbuilt function to specifically exclude products already on sale through a catalog rule.

When setting up your coupon code rule use this to exclude your Product A (and other on sale products)

[image: exclude SKUs]

One other approach is to create a new category (On Sale), which you can easily keep out of the navigation menu if you do not want to display it.

Then place your product A into the category.

When setting up the coupon code rule use this to exclude the on sale category

[image: exclude category]

Comment: Hi Fooman,
I've already thought about your second solution (creating a new category) and I find very strange that in Magento there isn't an inbuilt function for this type of requirement.
So, I would to ask to everybody if you know an extension that solves my issue.

Comment: +1 for this solution. I think this is the best so far. :) Maybe soon Magento will include this feature, but right now, this is the best way to implement it. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "Stop Further Rules Processing" settings present against promotion rules?
Please try using this setting for the catalog rule and shopping cart rule.

Comment: This will likely not work because one is a catalog price rule and the other one is shopping cart price rule.