# Doesn't apply coupon on the already discount products

Tags: discount, coupon, coupon-codes

Can I create a coupon that work with normal product but doesn't work with the already discount product?

I have Magento 1.9

I want to do this:

[image]

This is may dropdown menù on magento 1.9.2.3 I don't know why

[image]

Comment: There is not any in built feature like this but you can use solution given [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26427/shopping-cart-price-rule-that-excludes-discounted-products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on coupon action tab try this:

[image]

apply coupon only to those items for which special_price >= 0.1 is FALSE

set 0.1 to the minimum price you have.

tested on magento 1.9.2.1

try coupon code giveme333 on http://magento1.8.goivvy.com:8081/

add normal items and discounted items to the cart and see the result.

UPDATE:

how to add:

1. go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes , search for special_price and make sure 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' set to Yes.
2. click on green circle

[image]

3. from dropdown select first Special Price

[image]

3. change is to equals or greater
4. set 0.1

Comment: There isn't "Special price" option on my dropdown menu. I have only: Price in cart, Quantity in cart, Row total in cart, Attriburte set ,Category

Comment: see updated answer. pm me i will send you backend user/pass if needs be.

Comment: I add a screenshot of my dropdown menù in a question avobe

Comment: go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes , search for special_price and set 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' to Yes. save and try and see this dropdown again.